# Read HTML Elements from Code Behind using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I read a HTML Element like input type=checkbox from the code behind? Without adding `runat="server"`. Is that possible?

Comment: Please explain what do you want to do. I think you want to read rendered html. Right?

Comment: i have a input type=checkbox in my page and i want to know if it's checked or not from code behind. i dont want to use asp.net checkbox or add a runat=server to it. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, they're rendered as html literals and you can access them by using the `Controls` object.

Comment: can you give me an example? will appreciate it. tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the Request.Form collection to retrive those values

something along the lines of checking for this condition:

```
Request.Form("Name") != null
```

to check if the checkbox of name "Name" is checked.  If the box isn't checked that value will be null

Comment: It is not an ID of element, but its NAME.

Answer (score 6):

> How can i read a HTML Element like
>   input type=checkbox from the code
>   behind?

Before asking this you should first understand that **HTML Elements have nothing to do with the code-behind** (on the server).
You cannot access them in any way as you cannot access the client's browser from the server.

If you want to access THE VALUE of the INPUT element that is posted to the server then you should use:

```
var postedValue = Request.Form["nameOfElement"];
```

So if you have HTML:

```
<input type="check" name="nameOfElement" value="Yes" />
```

then:

- If user checked the element, then you will get "Yes" in the `postedValue`.
- Otherwise `postedValue` will be null.